# Custom git push ant task wont work in JGit

Tags: java, git, ant, jgit

I'm trying to complete my custom git-push ant task using JGit which should push stated branch to remote repository but it seems not to be working.

Here's my Java code for the task:

```
  public void setRepository(String repository) {
      this.repository = repository;
  }
  public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
  }   
  public void setUsername(String username) {
      this.username = username;
  }     
  public void setUri(String uri) {
      this.uri = uri;
  }     
  public void setBranch(String branch) {
      this.branch = branch;
  }


  public void execute() throws BuildException {
    try{

        Git git = Git.open(new File(repository));            
        CredentialsProvider cp = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(username, password);
        RefSpec spec = new RefSpec("refs/heads/" + branch + ":refs/heads/" + branch);

        PushCommand pushCommand = git.push();
         pushCommand.setCredentialsProvider(cp).setRemote(uri).setForce(true).setRefSpecs(spec).call();


    }catch (Exception e) {  
        log(e, Project.MSG_ERR);
        throw new BuildException("Could not push repository: " + e.getMessage(), e);

    }
```

And here's the line from Apache ant build file:

```
<gitpush 
    repository="./myrepo" 
    uri="ssh://username@host.com/repo/project.git" 
    branch="mybranch" 
    password="77CJr2xr" />
```

I create a new branch and try to run this task. The task run without exceptions but has no effect on remote repository. I'm very new to git so it could be really silly mistake. Am I doing something wrong with RefSpec?

Comment: `PushCommand#call()` returns a `PushResult` that in turn holds a collection of `RemoteRefUpdate`s. Did you inspect these? They should give you a clue what push actually did.

Comment: I get message:   `error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/mybranch (you should pull first)` tried to google for answer but no luck. Maybe I did something wrong by creating new empty branch using `git checkout --orphan mybranch` with `git rm --cached -r .` and then adding some files to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/...` is returned if someone else pushed to the same branch after you last fetched or cloned and before you tried to push.

```
you> git clone ...

bob> git clone ...
bob> git commit
bob> git push

you> git commit
you> git push   <<-- error: denying non-fast-forward
```

The `receive.denyNonFastForwards` configuration setting of the remote repository controls whether non-fast-forward updates are allowed. Usually this is not allowed as it would change the history of the remote repository. In the above example, Bob's commit would be lost.

Search for 'git push error denying non-fast-forward' to read more.